# Converting 10/11/2018 date string format to excel datevalue format using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is how do I convert 10/11/2018 date string format to excel datevalue format using python? I have a script which reads the last changed date from subversion, and this stored as a string and i write it on to an excel. But I want the date format as value. Similar to DATEVALUE in excel. Please help.

Comment: Please show your current attempts at a solution and any errors you're getting. Note: EXCEL doesn't have a single defined format for dates. If you write yyyyMMdd format, it'll interpret it, though

Answer (score 0):

THe DATEVALUE is the number of days since 01/01/1900, that date being day 1.

```
from datetime import date

d1 = date(1900, 1, 1)
dnow = date(2018, 11, 10)  # I didn't know whether it was UK or US date
datevalue = (dnow - d1).days + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to import the XLRD library, and then use the xlrd.xldate_from_date_tuple method.

```
import xlrd
xlrd.xldate.xldate_from_date_tuple((year, month, day),0)
```

datemode – 0: 1900-based, 1: 1904-based

Convert string to tuple:

```
#python3:

myDate='10/11/2018'
dateTuple=myDate.split('/')
resultDate=tuple(map(int,dateTuple))
year=resultDate[2]
month=resultDate[1]
day=resultDate[0]
print (year,month,day)

#python2:
myDate='10/11/2018'
dateTuple=myDate.split('/')
resultDate=map(int,dateTuple)
year=resultDate[2]
month=resultDate[1]
day=resultDate[0]
print (year,month,day)
```